# Android - Unable to save photo in specified location if the photo is under DCIM file

Tags: android, image, file, android-intent

I'm now facing a problem:

When trying to save photo into a specified location under the file of my app, if I choose a photo under **DCIM** file, my mobile(*HTC D816h version 4.4.2, has a SD card*) always stores photo in other wrong place. However, if it is a photo under **Pictures** file which I select, the cropped photo will be saved in the correct place.

On the other hand, when app runs on another mobile with same version(*HTC D626ph version 4.4.2*) as mine, there's nothing wrong and everything goes fine.

**Problem**

Why can't I store photos in a specified place if it comes to photos from DCIM file? And Why this problem happens only on my mobile?

**Procedure**

First, select a photo from gallery of mobile. Second, crop photo to whatever size you want. Third, save the cropped photo to the specified location in file of app. Last, display the cropped photo to `ImageView`.

I've made lots of research but still could not find a solution or reason for it. Hope I could get some help here. Thanks in advance!

Here's my code:

```
private Uri m_uriCropPhoto = null;

private void crop(Uri uriOrig) {
    File photo = null;

    try {
        String strFilePath = getFilePath(getActivity(), "profile_crop");
        photo = createFile(strFilePath);
    } catch(Exception e) {
        Log.i("Tag","Can't create file to take picture!");
    }

    m_uriCropPhoto = Uri.fromFile(photo);

    Intent intent = new Intent("com.android.camera.action.CROP");
    intent.setDataAndType(uriOrig, "image/*");

    List<ResolveInfo> list = getActivity().getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(intent, 0);

    if (list.size() == 0) {
        Log.i("Tag","Can't crop picture!");
    } else {
        intent.putExtra("crop", "true");
        intent.putExtra("return-data", false);
        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, m_uriCropPhoto);
        startActivityForResult(intent,SMyCardsFragment.REQUEST_CODE_CROP_PHOTO);
    }

}

private String getFilePath(String fileName) {
    File file = getActivity().getExternalFilesDir(null);

    if (file != null) {
        return String.format(Locale.getDefault(), "%s/%s%s", file.toString(), fileName, ".jpg");
    }

    return null;
}

private File createFile(String filePath) throws Exception {
    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(filePath) == true) {
        return null;
    }

    File file = new File(filePath);
    boolean isCreated = true;

    if (file.exists() == false) {
        isCreated = file.createNewFile();
    }

    return file;
}
```